# Loading images into a DIV tag

Tags: jquery

I have a list of images within a div tag with the id `sIMG`.

Example:

```
<div id="sIMG">
<img src="1.jpg" title=""/>
<img src="2.jpg" title=""/>
<img src="3.jpg" title=""/>
<img src="4.jpg" title=""/>
<img src="5.jpg" title=""/>
<img src="6.jpg" title=""/>
</div>
```

Now If I click on any image I need it to load into the `sIMG` div tag.

My code looks as follows, but only seems to load in the first image:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#sIMG img').click(function(){

        /* Get the sources */
        var currentSRC = jQuery('#sIMG img').attr('src');
        var altSRC = jQuery('#sIMG img').attr('title');
        alert(currentSRC)
        /*Fade, Callback, swap the alt and src, fade in */
        jQuery('#IMGHolder').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            jQuery('#IMGHolder').html('<img src='+currentSRC+' title='+altSRC+' />');
            jQuery('#IMGHolder').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`$(this`) to access the current element inside the event handler.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#sIMG img').click(function(){
            /* Get the sources */
            var currentSRC = jQuery(this).attr('src');

            var altSRC = jQuery(this).attr('title');

            alert(currentSRC);

            /*Fade, Callback, swap the alt and src, fade in */

            jQuery('#IMGHolder').fadeOut('fast',function(){
                jQuery(this).html('<img src='+currentSRC+' title='+altSRC+' />').fadeIn("fast");                    
            });
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing something wrong here?

Probably. Inside a handler `$(this)` will give you a jQuery handle on the object that was clicked. You'll probably want `jQuery(this)`.

What your current code does it goes out and looks for `img` elements regardless of the click event.

Your HTML is also malformed:

```
<div id="sIMG">
<img src="1.jpg" title=""/>
<img src="2.jpg" title="""/>
<img src="3.jpg" title="""/>
<img src="4.jpg" title="""/>
<img src="5.jpg" title="""/>
<img src="6.jpg" title=""/>
</div>
```

Should be

```
<div id="sIMG">
    <img src="1.jpg" title=""/>
    <img src="2.jpg" title=""/>
    <img src="3.jpg" title=""/>
    <img src="4.jpg" title=""/>
    <img src="5.jpg" title=""/>
    <img src="6.jpg" title=""/>
</div>
```

Ignore the indentation, it's the `"""` I took issue with.